# Why is Postgres (9.6) performing an additional sorting step when querying a sorted index?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-9.6

I have a table of geographic locations that looks more or less like this:

```
create table geoname(
  id int primary key, 
  name varchar(200), 
  population bigint,
  fclass char
  ...)
```

I want a query to perform an efficient, case insensitive prefix search on all rows that represent locations that have a population (i.e. `fclass = A|L|P`), order by greatest population and return the top 5 results.

I've created an index to speed it up as the table has 11m rows:

```
create index geoname_name_lower_sorted_idx 
    on geoname(lower(name) text_pattern_ops, population desc nulls last) 
    where (fclass = 'A' or fclass = 'L' or fclass = 'P');
```

An example query searching for locations starting with `cal` looks like this:

```
explain analyze
    select g.name from 
    geo.geoname g 
    where
        (g.fclass = 'A' or g.fclass = 'L' or g.fclass = 'P') and
        lower(g.name) like lower('cal%')
    order by g.population desc nulls last limit 10
```

However, from what I can see the query engine is running an explicit sorting step after it has scanned the index:

```
Limit  (cost=19.73..19.76 rows=10 width=22) (actual time=18.116..18.119 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=19.73..21.02 rows=516 width=22) (actual time=18.114..18.115 rows=10 loops=1)
        Sort Key: population DESC NULLS LAST
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Index Scan using geoname_name_lower_sorted_idx on geoname g  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=516 width=22) (actual time=0.030..17.060 rows=5798 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((lower((name)::text) ~>=~ 'cal'::text) AND (lower((name)::text) ~<~ 'cam'::text))
              Filter: (lower((name)::text) ~~ 'cal%'::text)
Planning time: 0.261 ms
Execution time: 18.356 ms
```

My understanding of sorted indexes is that this wouldn't be necessary as the index is already ordered.

I would expect it not to need to perform this last step.

Comment: If I'd reading this right, it's spending an extra whole two *milliseconds* on this. Do those two milliseconds make or break your application? Remember, the goal of optimizers is to be good enough, not best possible.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever correct, its not a problem, I'm just trying to learn. It might be doing the sort afterwards because its more efficient that way for a smaller batch of results.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use an index for both filtering and sorting unless the conditions are the same.

It should work if the `ORDER BY` clause that matches the index:

```
ORDER BY lower(name) COLLATE "C" NULLS LAST
```

Answer (score -1):

This is your query:

```
select g.name from 
geo.geoname g 
where g.fclass in ('A', 'L', 'P') and
      lower(g.name) like 'cal%'
order by g.population desc nulls last
limit 10;
```

Postgres cannot use the index for the sorting because of the `like` pattern.  Each `g.name` is sorted separately in the index.  Instead, you might be able to use:

```
on geoname(substr(lower(name), 1, 3) text_pattern_ops, population desc nulls last)
```

And then:

```
select g.name from 
geo.geoname g 
where g.fclass in ('A', 'L', 'P') and
      substr(lower(g.name), 1, 3) = 'cal' and
order by g.population desc nulls last
limit 10;
```

Comment: Yup this makes sense - what I didn't make clear in the original question is that the search term can be of varying length.

Comment: So does this essentially mean that the ordering can only happen if the first index value resolves to a single "bucket", as it would in your example? And that in my example the sorting is done later because the first part of the query returns multiple buckets for a particular prefix value, so it has to combine and sort them.

Comment: @mistakenot . . . That is a good way of describing the situation.  The index can be used for sorting if the selecting values are all adjacent in the index.